# After exporting it with Eclipse, my runnable JAR doesn't open, probably because of resources

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I've searched through dozens of threads all over the Internet (including stackoverflow) and I haven't found anything that helped me, maybe because I'm too dumb to understand it. I'm kind of new to Java so that might be it.

Anyway, the program runs perfectly inside Eclipse, it gets all the needed images, files, etc. Once I export it as a runnable JAR, I can't open it, not even with the command prompt (says "Unable to access).

This is what I tried, importing the resources:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;

public class Loader {

    public static String path = "/Z:/Eclipse/workspace/FirstGame/src/";

    static File smoothFont;
    static File roughFont;
    static File alahuSong;
    static File deathAlahu;
    static File hitSoundAlahu;
    static File hitSoundBit;
    static File deathBit;
    static File hpBit;
    static File selectbit;
    static File songBit;
    static File colorFile;
    static File easyScoreFile;
    static File normalScoreFile;
    static File hardScoreFile;
    static File insaneScoreFile;
    static File meSteam;
    static File manelFaxe;
    static File mePassado;
    static File manelSteam;

    public static void load(Game game) {
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/summerStormSmooth.ttf");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/summerStormRough.ttf");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/alahuSong.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/deathAlahu.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/hitSoundAlahu.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/hitSoundBit.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/deathBit.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/hpBit.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/selectBit.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/songBit.ogg");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/colorFile.txt");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/easyScoreFile.txt");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/normalScoreFile.txt");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/hardScoreFile.txt");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/insaneScoreFile.txt");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/meSteam.png");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/manelFaxe.png");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/mePassado.png");
        game.getClass().getResource(path + "res/manelSteam.png");
    }
}
```

Also, this is how my build is organized:
[:D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q5kE.png)

I can give you any more information you need, thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is Game.class is located? the res folder should be in the same location as Game.class

Comment: Try this: `game.getClass().getResource("/res/summerStormSmooth.ttf");` or `game.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/summerStormSmooth.ttf")`

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab Game.class is inside the "main" package, while all the resources are inside the "res" folder, which is NOT inside the "main" package. Are you saying if I move the "res" inside the "main" package it should work? Thanks!

Comment: @user2004685 Have tried both, none works. Any idea of how to find the correct paths? Thanks!

Comment: Try opening the JAR File and try to locate your resources. If they are not inside any folder then you can use something like: `game.getClass().getResource("/summerStormSmooth.ttf");`

Comment: @user2004685 I've found them, but still not working.

Comment: If res folder is inside main folder. Game.class.getResource("/res/summerStormSmooth.ttf") or getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/res/summerStormSmooth.ttf") should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an invalid String value.  The String argument accepted by [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) is not a file name.

You should be passing a path relative to the root of your .jar.  If you're not sure exactly which files are in your .jar file, either examine the .jar file in Eclipse, or use a Command Window to view the .jar file with **jar tf** *MyApplication.jar*.

If your project is set up correctly, it probably bundles the contents of the `res` directory into your final .jar file, in which case the correct way to invoke Class.getResource is:

```
static URL smoothFont;
static URL roughFont;
// ...
static URL colorFile;
// ...
static URL meSteam;

public static void load(Game game) {
    smoothFont = Loader.class.getResource("/summerStormSmooth.ttf");
    roughFont = Loader.class.getResource("/summerStormRough.ttf");
    // ...
    colorFile = Loader.class.getResource("/colorFile.txt");
    // ...
    meSteam = Loader.class.getResource("/meSteam.png");
    // ...
}
```

You *cannot* refer to your data as `File`s when they are inside a .jar file, because they're just entries in the .jar file—byte sequences representing compressed data—and not actual separate files.

Fortunately, loading a URL is just as easy as loading a File:

```
Font loadedSmoothFont;
try (InputStream stream = smoothFont.openStream()) {
    loadedSmoothFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream);
}

String colorFileContents;
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(colorFile.openStream())) {
    colorFileContents = scanner.useDelimiter("\\z").next();
}

BufferedImage meSteamImage = ImageIO.read(meSteam);
```

Comment: Ok, this is really helpful, I'll see what I can do with this info, and I'll get back to you! Thank you so much.

Comment: Wait, so after I load them (your second code piece), can I use them all across all classes?

Comment: Yes.  `Loader.class` is just used as a basis for locating them;  once you obtain the URL, the URL is independent of any particular class.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot.